Instance member 'profile' cannot be used on type 'GIDGoogleUser'
I was following a tutorial on YouTube about a messaging app. The tutorial was old and the google SDK was updated which then made my code full of errors. For a couple of days I have been trying to fix it and even found someone else's updated code which showed how to do it but my code still has errors. I'm new to coding and cannot figure out how to make my Google sign in button work. I have skipped over the other code and only added in the code for the google sign in button on the login View Controller.
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

// More code for login options

   private let googleLoginButton: GIDSignInButton = {
        let button = GIDSignInButton()
        button.style = GIDSignInButtonStyle.wide
        button.colorScheme = GIDSignInButtonColorScheme.dark
        return button

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 googleLoginButton.addTarget(self,
                                    action: #selector(googleButtonTapped),
                                    for: .touchUpInside)

        scrollView.addSubview(googleLoginButton)

googleLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 30,
                                         y: facebookLoginButton.bottom+10,
                                         width: scrollView.width-60,
                                         height: 52)


// line 249 down 
    @objc func googleButtonTapped() {
        guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
            let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: self) { result, error in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Fail to sign in with Google: \(error)")
                return
                
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else {
                return
            }
            
            guard let email = user.profile?.email,
                  let firstName = user?.profile?.givenName,
                  let lastName = user?.profile?.familyName else {
                return
            }
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
            UserDefaults.standard.set("\(firstName) \(lastName)", forKey: "name")
            
           
            
            print("Did sign in with Google: \(user)")
            DatabaseManager.shared.userExists(with: email) { exists in
                if !exists {
                    // insert to database
                    let chatUser = ChatAppUser(firstName: firstName,
                                               lastName: lastName,
                                               emailAddress: email)
                    DatabaseManager.shared.insertUser(with: chatUser) { success in
                        if success {
                            // upload image
                            guard let userProfile = user.profile else {
                                return
                            }
                            if userProfile.hasImage {
                                guard let url = userProfile.imageURL(withDimension: 200) else {
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
                                    guard let data = data else {
                                        return
                                    }
                                    
                                    let fileName = chatUser.profilePictureFileName
                                    StorageManager.shared.uploadProfilePicture(with: data,
                                                                               fileName: fileName) { result in
                                        switch result {
                                        case .success(let downloadUrl):
                                            UserDefaults.standard.set(downloadUrl, forKey: "profile_picture_url")
                                            print(downloadUrl)
                                        case .failure(let error):
                                            print("Storage manager error: \(error)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }.resume()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
 let authentication = user.authentication
            guard let idToken = authentication.idToken else { return }
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                           accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
            
            FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { [weak self]authResult, error in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                guard authResult != nil, error == nil else {
                    print("failed to log in google credential")
                    return
                }
                
                print("Successfully signed in google credential.")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didLogInNotification, object: nil)
                strongSelf.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }
        }
    }


Look up google documentation
Look up apple documentation
Look up the various errors online when I made the changed and new error popped up.

Value of type 'GIDGoogleUser' has no member 'authentication'

Where does the user come from? I believe it should be guard let user = result?.user instead of  guard let user = GIDGoogleUser

Yeah I had it like this before but it just created another error... "Value of type 'GIDGoogleUser' has no member 'authentication'" added the authentication code to the above.

The code is confusing because some braces are missing and the indentation is a mess. And as user is non-optional user?.profile? must throw a compilation error.

Yeah it really is a mess. Probably better off scrapping the google sign in and just continuing the tutorial! I'm sure it will make more sense with some more experience.
